# question about sub-collections in node-red firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, node-red

I'm a beginner in node-red and I'm using the "node-red-contrib-cloud-firestore" and I have a question that I can't find anywhere. In my firestore, I have a collection with two documents and within those documents I have another collection in both.

[image: my firestore image]

I would like to receive data from the entire collection, with the document and the sub-collections. I know that I can receive by defining the collection on each node as: "place / House / user", but I would like to receive all data from "House" and "Mom house".

Is there a way to do this?